Why are extra characters created with MakeBoxes?
Consider a symbol that looks like this one: $a_b$
This question is about the behavior MakeBoxes on strings that contain boxes.
Try this:
Iconize $a_b$ and then Un-Iconize it---no problem.
Now try this:
Iconize the string "$a_b$" and then Un-Iconize it.  You will see a bunch of escaped characters:
"\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\),b\)]\)".  Iconizing is not reversible.
I think MakeBoxes is what is creating this behavior.
Compare (replacing char with a_b):
MakeBoxes[char]

and
MakeBoxes["char"]

Why is that happening and is there a good work-around to get Iconize to be reversible?
StringReplace[ "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)", {"\\!" -> "",  "\\(" -> ""}]
is a possible work around, but is there something less kludgy?

Strings don't have subscripts in them, so if you have something that looks like a string with a subscript that is just the front end displaying the string nicely but not showing the actual contents of the string.  Try ToString[<<your string here>>, InputForm] to see what it really looks like.

@JasonB. It seems the "Uniconize" button in the iconized string is mis-parsing the string.  The uniconized string has a syntax error.

I guess I should point out that the outputs of uniconizing and MakeBoxes are different. So I don't think it's a MakeBoxes problem. Maybe.

@MichaelE2 I don't think the string has syntax errors, it's just showing its true form. Type a string with a subscript in an Input cell, then highlight the string and hit Cell->Convert To->StandardForm and you see the same linear syntax string. You can use it anywhere you would have used the original 'nice' form, in an output cell it will look as expected.  Running the StringReplace command in the question here actually does nothing.

@Jason B Hmm, I thought it was the MakeBoxes.   Here is the case where this problem was annoying me.  Suppose I have a plot and I iconize a long list of Options.  If one of the options is PlotLabel-> " label with sub/super/fraction boxes" , then Iconizing/Uniconizing destroys the original form and makes it difficult to edit.

@JasonB. It's Mathematica that tells me there is a syntax error. No thought required: https://i.sstatic.net/QtfgZ.png -- A look at the box structure (Show Expression) shows it has a different structure than the input string: https://i.sstatic.net/2rkIx.png

@JasonB. Just to be clear: I don't think there's a syntax problem with input string "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)". The problem is with the output of the Uniconize button, after the string is iconized.

The problem is that the un-iconized output is a string, not an expression.  "\"\\!\\(\\*SubscriptBox[\\(a\\), \\(b\\)]\\)\"" // ToExpression  will evaluate the expression.

Is the conclusion that this behavior only is due to Iconize?   I was also running into this during a notebook programming task: something like (can’t check syntax because I am typing on a phone). list/.SomeBox[a_,b_]:>SomeBox[Characters[a],Characters[b]]   I’ll need to check that snippet and make sure that reproduces the problem when Iconize is not involved.

Two alternative approaches to string plot labels that I use are Row[]/HoldForm[] and the MaTeX package.

Consider Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)"] //    Unevaluated // Iconize, where the expanded string boxes were entered in "2D" format in the FE. If I evaluate this and un-iconize it, I get "$a_b$" in an Output cell. If I edit this or convert to Input, then the subscript is preserved. OTOH, if I evaluate the code in place, I get an icon in the input cell; when that is un-iconized, I get the expanded string-box form with a SubscriptBox, and it's a pain to get pack it back into the desired subscripted form. Is that the problem you're trying to avoid?

@Goofy  Yes, that is a problem I am trying to avoid.  The same issue arises on some other things I am playing with--but it the iconize/uniconize thing worked, I think my other problems will go away.

Uniconizing "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)" // Iconize creates an ungrammatical box structure.
I see something different than what is being discussed in the comments ("14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)", in case it matters). And it seems to be a bug. The OP's remarks sometimes seem centered on a different issue. A clear use-case (example) is not given, beyond the one that led me to the issue below. The non-issue, which others focus on in the comments, is the string representation "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)" of subscripts. The buggy issue is what happens to this when you iconize it and then uniconize it. The longer the discussion in the comments goes on, the more it seems likely that the OP is interested in the ameliorating the inconvenience of the non-issue in plot labels and has not noticed the issue below which addresses the code that was explicitly asked about. An XY Problem, perhaps.
The bug
One of the outputs in Out[301] below is the output of uniconizing and one is the output of FullForm — can you guess which?

But wait! The inputs in In[301] look the same! However their internal box structure is different. Here are the output cells generated by uniconizing Iconize and by FullForm:

$I.$
The syntax errors come from the individual "\"" and "\\!". When these are replaced by "Q" and "ESC", which strings represent symbols, the expression is parsed without errors.
$\;{I}{I}.$
For some reason the strings "\\(", "\\) and "\\*" are ignored. RowBox[{"\\(", "a", "\\)"}] is interpreted as the String expression "a" (same for "b").
$\;{I}{I}{I}.$
The nested RowBox-es are interpreted as nested Times[] or function expressions. For instance, RowBox[{"f", "[", RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}] is f[x, y]. This construction appears once above with SubscriptBox for f. Note it is (i) RowBox[{"SubscriptBox", "[", ..., "]"}], not (ii) SubscriptBox["a", "b"], which is the box form for (iii) Subscript[a, b]. Box expression (i) is in effect the box form of the box form of (iii), but with nonstandard expressions for argument strings "a", and "b".
Here is what MakeExpression makes of the boxes from the uniconized string with the ungrammatical tokens "\"" and "\\!" replaced by "Q" and "ESC".
MakeExpression[
  RowBox[{"Q",
    RowBox[{"ESC",
      RowBox[{"\\(",
        RowBox[{"\\*",
          RowBox[{"SubscriptBox"
            , "["
            , RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"\\(", "a", "\\)"}], ",", " ",
              RowBox[{"\\(", "b", "\\)"}]}]
            , "]"}]}],
        "\\)"}]}], "Q"}]
  , StandardForm] // FullForm

(*  HoldComplete[Times[Q, Times[ESC, SubscriptBox["a", "b"]], Q]]  *)


You are right, the question would have been better had I articulated a use case.  I had/have several problems in mind I thought they all stemmed from what I was seeing from MakeBox.   However, the best use case example is this:  When I iconify a something with a string that has boxes (often done with FrameLabel), the uniconified result is something that still works but is hard to edit (and is ugly).

And, thank you for that deep spelunking that you did above.
